# Spotify API Detect Play/Stop Event

Tags: javascript, dom-events, spotify

I am using the Spotify App API, I was successful getting the music to play via the `player.play(URI)` method. However this does not address when someone press the play button from the actual Spotify Player. I tried looking into `player.observe(models.EVENT.CHANGE)` method but its firing twice for every press. [I saw This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13175807/spotify-api-player-event-change-triggers-twice) post suggesting I install some third party app, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

`player.observe(models.EVENT.CHANGE)` is the correct way to do it. It's a bug that it's firing twice, but for now you can simply filter out one of the events.